# Show that there exists $\xi_i \in l^2(\Gamma)$ with $\|\xi_i\|=1$ such that $\|\lambda_s \xi_i-\xi_i\| \to 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $Γ$ be a discrete abelian group. We denote the group ring of $Γ$ by $\mathbb{C}(Γ)$, which is the set of all formal sums of the form $∑_{s∈Γ}a_ss$, where only finitely many of the scalar coefficients $a_s∈\mathbb{C}$ are nonzero.The reduced $C^∗$−algebra of $\Gamma$, denoted by $C^∗_{λ}(Γ)$, is the completion of $\mathbb{C}(Γ)$ with respect to the norm
$||x||_r=||λ(x)||_{B(l^2(Γ))}$
where $λ:Γ→B(l^2(Γ))$ is defined by $λ(s)(δ_t)=δ_{st},∀s,t∈Γ$.

> Suppose that $C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma)$ has a character (i.e one dimensional representation).  Show that there exists $\xi_i \in l^2(\Gamma)$ with $\|\xi_i\|=1$ such that $\|\lambda_s \xi_i-\xi_i\| \to 0$

Let $\phi: C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma) \to \mathbb{C}$ be the one dimensional representation.  Then $1=\overline{\phi}(ss^{-1})=\overline{\phi}(s)\overline{\phi}(s^{-1}) \implies 1=|\overline{\phi}(s)||\overline{\phi}(s^{-1})|$. Since $1=\phi(\lambda_s \circ \lambda_{s}^*)=\phi(\lambda_s)\phi(\lambda_{s}^*)=\phi(\lambda_s)\overline{\phi(\lambda_s)}=|\phi(\lambda_s)|^2$ gives us that $|\phi(\lambda_s)|=1$ which is equivalent to saying that $|\overline{\phi}(s)|=1 $ for all $s \in \Gamma$.

Since every state on $C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma)$ can be approximated by vector states coming from $l^2(\Gamma)$, there exists $\xi_i \in l^2(\Gamma)$ such that $|\phi(x)-\langle x\xi_i,\xi_i\rangle| \to 0$ for $x \in C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma)$ as $i \to \infty$. In particular, $|\phi(\lambda_s)-\langle \lambda_s\xi_i,\xi_i\rangle| \to 0$ for all $s \in \Gamma$. This along with the above observation gives us that $|\langle \lambda_s\xi_i,\xi_i\rangle| \to 1$ for all $s \in \Gamma$.

Now $$\|\lambda_s(\xi_i)-\xi_i\|^2=\langle\lambda_s(\xi_i)-\xi_i,\lambda_s(\xi_i)-\xi_i \rangle=2-\langle\lambda_s(\xi_i),\xi_i\rangle-\langle\xi_i,\lambda_s(\xi_i)\rangle$$

To prove the assertion, I need to show that $\langle \lambda_s\xi_i,\xi_i\rangle \to 1$. I am unable to conclude this from whatever I have shown till now. How do I show this?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: And why is that @reuns?

Comment: A couple things I can comment on: every abelian C$^*$-algebra has many characters, so it is awkward to state the existence of one character as a hypothesis. Also, your $\bar\phi$ plays no role: the fact that $\phi$ is a one-dimensional representation guarantees that $|\phi(\lambda_s)|=1$, since $\lambda_s$ is a unitary.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Professor, I am trying to prove that existence of a character leads to the assertion I am trying to prove. I didn't know how to frame it otherwise

Comment: What a mess. Why not state clearly what you want to show ? In what you wrote you treat only things like $\sum_{t \in \Gamma} a_t \delta_t \mapsto \sum_{t \in \Gamma} a_t \delta_{st}$ while you start with the algebra of convolutions operators $\sum_{t \in \Gamma} a_t \delta_t \mapsto \sum_s c_s \sum_{t \in \Gamma} a_t \delta_{s t}$.

Comment: @reuns I don't deal with algebra of convolution operators, atleast the way I see it.  I mentioned what I wanted to show in the very beginning. The mentioned thing in the end is what I need to show to conclude

Comment: Your norm is impossible to understand. The multiplication in the group ring is a convolution.

Comment: The multiplication is defined by $\left(\sum_{s \in \Gamma}a_s s\right)\left(\sum_{t \in \Gamma}b_t t\right)=\sum_{s,t \in \Gamma}a_sb_tst$. The involution is defined by declaring $\left(\sum_{s \in \Gamma}a_s s\right)^*=\sum_{s \in \Gamma}\bar{a_s}s^{-1}$.

Comment: The norm of an element is the basically looking at the norm of the element inside $B(l^2(\Gamma))$ via left regular representation

Comment: I think reuns is out of line. But you could be clearer, in that you write $\lambda$ with domain in $\Gamma$, but then you treat it as its linear extension to $\mathbb C(\gamma)$. And you wrote $C(\Gamma)$, which confuses things a bit more.

Comment: You also need the requirement that $\|\xi_i\|=1$, because otherwise the property is trivial.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Yeah. I forgot the norm.

Answer (score 2):

Note that what you want to show is that $1\in\sigma(\lambda_s)$. I don't really see how to make your argument work.

An abelian group is [amenable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group). One of the equivalent conditions for amenability (called *Dixmier Property* in the Wikipedia article) is precisely what you are looking for.

Reconstructing the actual sequence of vectors from the above argument looks hard: basically what one needs is a Følner sequence.

---

Here is a bit more information. If you try to write things explicitly for a small group, say $\mathbb Z_2$, it is quickly clear that $\lambda(s)$ are permutations. These indeed have $1$ as an eigenvalue, and the obvious eigenvectors are those with all entries equal.

Trying to extend this idea ("all entries equal") to a infinite group doesn't work directly.  For each $F\subset \Gamma$ finite, define
$$
\xi_F=\frac1{\sqrt{|F|}}\sum_{t\in F} \delta_t.
$$
Then
$$
\|\xi_F\|^2=\frac1{|F|}\sum_{s,t\in F}\langle \delta_t,\delta_s\rangle=1.
$$
Let $s\in \Gamma$. Then
$$
\|\lambda_s\xi_F-\xi_F\|^2=\frac{|sF\Delta F|}{|F|},
$$
and that's where we need the Følner sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I claim that the character from $C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma)$ can be assumed to take $\lambda_s$ to constant $1$ for all $s \in \Gamma$. If I am able to show this, then this would give me $|1-\langle \lambda_s \xi_i,\xi_i \rangle| \to 0$ as $i \to \infty$ for all $s \in \Gamma$. This coupled with the calculation at the end will give me the result. All that remains to be shown is the claim.

> Claim: The product of two positive definite functions on $\Gamma$ coming from two different states on $C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma)$ is a positive definite function. Moreover the positive function obtained in this way also comes from a state on $C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma)$.

Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two positive definite functions on from $\Gamma$ to $\mathbb{C}$, which come from two different states $\omega_{\phi}$ and $\omega_{\psi}$ on $C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma)$. Define $\xi:\Gamma \to \mathbb{C}$ by $\xi(s)=\phi(s)\psi(s)$ Let $F=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_k\} \subset \Gamma$. Then $$\left[{\xi}(s^{-1}t)\right]_{s,t \in F}= \left[\phi(s^{-1}t)\psi(s^{-1}t)\right]_{s,t \in F}$$

This product is known as Hadamard Product. The Hadamard product of two positive definite matrices is positive definite. Let $A$ and $B$ be two positive definite matrices. Let the Hadamard product be denoted by $A \circ B$. Then $$x^* (A \circ B)x=\text{Tr}{(D_x^*AD_xB^*)}=\text{Tr}{\left(D_x^*A^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}D_x(B^{\frac{1}{2}})^*(B^{\frac{1}{2}})^*\right)}$$
$$=\text{Tr}{\left((B^{\frac{1}{2}})^*D_x^*A^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}D_x(B^{\frac{1}{2}})^*\right)}=\text{Tr}{\left((B^{\frac{1}{2}})^*D_x^*A^{\frac{1}{2}}A^{\frac{1}{2}}D_xB^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)}\ge0$$
This shows that ${\xi}$ is a positive definite function on $\Gamma$.
$\overline{\omega_{\phi}}: \mathbb{C}(\Gamma) \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\overline{\omega_{\phi}}\left(\sum_{s}a_s s\right)=\sum_{s}a_s\phi(s)$ extends to a state on $C^*(\Gamma)$.

Since I want to define a state on $C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma)$, I want to have a map which looks like this:
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma) & & \ra{} & C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma)\otimes 1 && \ra{} & C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma) \otimes C^*(\Gamma) && \ra{} & \mathbb{C} \otimes C^*(\Gamma) && \ra{} && \mathbb{C}  \\
\end{array}
$$
which sends 
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
\sum_s a_s s & & \ra{} & \sum_s a_s s\otimes 1 && \ra{} & \sum_s a_s(\lambda_s \otimes s) && \ra{} &\sum_s a_s(\omega_{\psi}(\lambda_s) \otimes s)  && \ra{} && \overline{\omega_{\phi}}\left(\sum_s\omega_{\psi}(\lambda_s)a_s s\right)  \\
\end{array}
$$

It can be checked that the map defined this way gives rise to a state.

> Now Let $\Phi$ be a character on $C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma)$. Then the map $f: \Gamma \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(s)=\Phi(\lambda_s)$ is a positive definite function on $\Gamma$. Similarly the map $g: \Gamma \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $g(s)=\Phi(\lambda_{s^{-1}})$ is a positive definite function on $\Gamma$. Hence, by the above claim, the map $h: \Gamma \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $h(s)=f(s)g(s)$ is a positive definite function and comes from a state $\Lambda$ on $C_{\lambda}^*(\Gamma)$. Moreover $\Lambda(\lambda_s)=h(s)=1$ for all $s \in \Gamma$.